# what's the cut line between future predictions and future intentions?

Tags: grammar

> he's sick. **he's going to see a doctor**.

I don't know is it a prediction or intention? I need a crucial point to differentiate between the two ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**He is going to see a doctor** is a statement. It is an assertion. We don't know who **he** is or whether the statement is true or a line from a movie. So there is no point in asking whether it is a prediction or intention. Only the context would make it clearer.

Comment: I just want to know how a native may figure out the meaning

Comment: It's as meaningful as saying that **there are clouds in the sky**. It's just a statement. What is signifies can only be ascertained from the context.

Comment: so what's the priority to the mind if there is a lack in the context? is it intention or prediction?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is both. I make the statement because he has told me he is going. It might be a prediction only, if I see him walking towards the doctor's door. It is less likely to be expressing intention only; that could be expressed "He intends to see a doctor, but I bet he doesn't."